# How to infer an android attribute at runtime?

Tags: android, layout, attributes

the below preference definition references a simple layout (view_profile_remove) with a single ImageButton to be included in the widget-part of preferences.xml. The button works as intended, however the preference itself cannot be clicked or selected anymore. In order to be working as desired, I should include the layout-attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the underlying preference layout, however, the corresponding preferences.xml is not accessible to me, since it is a system layout.

How can I infer this attribute at runtime ?

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:defaultValue="Black"
    android:key="prof_key_player2"
    android:summary="Black"
    android:title="2. Player"
    android:widgetLayout="@layout/view_profile_remove" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to my problem without the need to write a custom preference or to infer anything:

I just copied the systems provided preference.xml layout file to my project res/layout/ folder and made the following changes:

added the required attribute

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the outermost LinearLayout-element and
removed all "+" symbols in the id-declarations

Then I added the manipulated layout in the preferences xml like this:

```
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Black"
        android:key="prof_key_player2"
        android:summary="Black"
        android:title="2. Player"
        android:layout="@layout/preference"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/view_profile_remove" />
```

Works fine, no focusability problems anymore.